# Install niceforms. Send options to cart

Tags: magento, product, cart, niceforms

I want to install [niceforms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/) on Magento.

How does it work? I wrap the product option "select" info form tag so it looks like

```
<form class ="niceform">
<divs for niceform>
<select id="" class="product-custom-option required-...." ...>
</form>
```

So
div for niceforms contains duplicate of select in div-format. So I managed to write a function which will watch selected element from divs and select it in product-option select. And then reload price. But it doesn't sends product-options to cart.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that niceform was in another form.